# error when replacing missing ')' using negative look ahead regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to look ahead for missing ')' and add them with re.sub but I get strange results when using negative looka ahead:

```py
a='D, M, departementsråd (fr.o.m. 2018-11-22 t.o.m. 2021-09-30 E, A, chef för Statens haverikommission (fr.o.m. 1997-07-01 t.o.m. 1997-09-07)'
re.sub(r'(t\.o\.m\.\s*\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})(?!\))',r'\1\)',a)
```

result:

```
D, M, departementsråd (fr.o.m. 2018-11-22 t.o.m. 2021-09-30\\) E, A, chef för Statens haverikommission (fr.o.m. 1997-07-01 t.o.m. 1997-09-0\\)7)
```

what I want:

```
D, M, departementsråd (fr.o.m. 2018-11-22 t.o.m. 2021-09-30) E, A, chef för Statens haverikommission (fr.o.m. 1997-07-01 t.o.m. 1997-09-0)
```

I want to add the missing `)` in `t.o.m. 2021-09-30` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that result because the `\d{1,2}` leaves paths to explore using backtracking due to the `{1,2}`

This part `\d{1,2}(?!\))` will match 1 or 2 digits asserting what is directly on the right is not `)` which it can match for `0` in `07)`

What you might do is use a word boundary `\d{1,2}\b`

```
t\.o\.m\.\s*\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\b(?!\))
```

In the replacement you could use the full match instead of using group 1

```
\g<0>)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZDZPyJ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/E8gZ89)